# download attribute for href doesn't work for png

Tags: html, download, href

I'm using the download href attribute to force the browser to download files. It works but in the case of png it does not:

```
<a class="esdc-AnchorBtn save" title="Download the image file in PNG format" href="http://csaint.esac.esa.int/ftp_public/jcook022221192/CSA_CG_PREGEN_6HOUR_jcook02_20181031_154434__20060111000000.png" download=""></a>
```

The image is rendered in the current browser window or a new tab if I add the target="_blank".

I guess this is happening because the Content-Type returned is "image/png"

Is there someway to force the browser to save the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be going on.

But first, the `download` attribute only works under the [following conditions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes);

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs. (ex: the page with the link must be on the domain `csaint.esac.esa.int`, as that is where hte link points to.)
>
> Although HTTP(s) URLs need to be in the same-origin, blob: URLs and data: URLs are allowed so that content generated by JavaScript, such as pictures created in an image-editor Web app, can be downloaded. (In your case, is your page HTTPS?)
>
> If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this attribute.
>
> If Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox prioritizes Content-Disposition, like the filename case, while Chrome prioritizes the download attribute.

In terms of your syntax, if you don't want to change the filename it should look like this:

```
<a [...] href='example.com/image.jpg' download></a>
```

If you want to change the filename, that is when you should set the attribute to have a value.

```
<a [...] href='example.com/image.jpg' download='myImage.jpg'></a>
```

When it comes to browser availability, it is pretty good. There are some that do not support it however, like IE. You can take a look at the details here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download
[image: caniuse graph]